# CakePHP 3: Undefined index while redirecting with variables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am implementing the functionality for an admin to generate `.csv` files with all the data from the table `Events` in a certain period of time.

This is an option in the main menu so first I want to take the user to `exportcsv.ctp` view where he can choose the desired date range. Then I redirect him to `redirecttoexport` method in `EventsController` where I get the afformentioned date range into variables and pass them to `export` method which generate `.csv` file.

The `export` method is fine, I tested it.

The problem is I'm still getting these errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: beginning [APP/Controller\EventsController.php, line 212]
Notice (8): Undefined index: end [APP/Controller\EventsController.php, line 213]
```

And I don't know how to fix it and how exactly should I pass these variables from view to the method. I checked CakePHP Cookbook several times, but I'm too inexperienced in this framework to understand everything. They assumed that the user has some kind of knowledge which I certainly lack of.

Any ideas?

**`exportcsv` and `redirecttoexport` methods in `EventsController`:**

```php
public function exportcsv()
{

}

public function redirecttoexport($id = null)
{
  $beginning = (string)$this->request->data['beginning'];
  $end =  $this->request->data['end'];

  return $this->redirect(['action' => 'export', 'controller' => 'Events', $beginning, $end]);

}
```

**`export` method in `EventsController`:**

```
public function export($first, $second)
{
        $this->response->download('export.csv');
        $data = $this->Events->find('all')
                          ->select([
                            'title',
                            'created',
                            'description',
                            'ended',
                            'working_hours',
                            'price',
                            'username' => 'Users.name',
                            'statusname' => 'Statuses.name',
                            'employeename' => 'Employees.name'
                          ])
                          ->leftJoinWith('Statuses')
                          ->leftJoinWith('Users')
                          ->leftJoinWith('Employees')
                          ->where(["created BETWEEN " . $first . " AND " . $second])
                          ->autoFields(true)
                          ->toArray();
    $_serialize = 'data';
    $_delimiter = chr(9); //tab
    $_extract = ['title', 'created', 'description', 'ended', 'working_hours', 'price', 'username', 'statusname', 'employeename'];
    $this->set(compact('data', '_serialize','_delimiter', '_extract'));
    $this->viewBuilder()->className('CsvView.Csv');
    return;
  }
```

**`exportcsv.ctp` view:**

```
<div class="events form large-6 medium-4 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create('Export', ['url'=>['action' => 'redirecttoexport', 'controller' => 'Events']]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('beginning', array('type'=>'datetime', 'interval' => 15, 'label' => 'Beginning:')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('end', array('type'=>'datetime',  'interval' => 15, 'label' => 'End:')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Add')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I did some debugging: 
`debug($this->request->data);` shows:

```
[
 'beginning' => [
    'year' => '2016',
    'month' => '06',
    'day' => '23',
    'hour' => '11',
    'minute' => '15'
  ],
  'end' => [
    'year' => '2016',
    'month' => '06',
    'day' => '29',
    'hour' => '11',
    'minute' => '15'
   ]
]
```

**EDIT:**

I edited my code so it is now more compact and easier to read:

**`exportcsv` method in `EventsController`**

```
public function exportcsv($beginning = null, $end = null)
{
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $beginning = $this->request->data['Export']['beginning'];  //line 206
  $end = $this->request->data['Export']['end'];              //line 207

  return $this->redirect([$beginning, $end]);
 }

 if (!$beginning && !$end) {
  return $this->render();
 }

 /* existing export action code *\
}
```

**`exportcsv.ctp` view:**

```
<div class="events form large-6 medium-4 columns content">
  <?= $this->Form->create('Export'); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('beginning', array('type'=>'datetime', 'interval' => 15, 'label' => 'Beginning:')); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('end', array('type'=>'datetime',  'interval' => 15, 'label' => 'End:')); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->button(__('Add')) ?>
  <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

But I'm still getting these errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: Export [APP/Controller\EventsController.php, line 206]
Notice (8): Undefined index: Export [APP/Controller\EventsController.php, line 207]
```

Comment: What code is in line 212 and 213 of your `EventsController.php`? Did you also try to debug `$first` and `$second`? Why are you using 3 actions and redirects to solve 1 task? Couldn't this all be done within one action? `if ($this->request->is('post')) {` CSV response `} else {` show date select form...

Comment: Do not specify string in your form *create* call. Specify **null** instead. Like this : 
`<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['action' => 'redirecttoexport', 'controller' => 'Events']]) ?>`
 You can either put entity there or null/false. [ref](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#starting-a-form)

Comment: @Oops D'oh I edited my code after your suggestions so it is now easier to read. Both variables show `null` values. @Gaurav I did as you suggested but then how could I assign values to `$beginning` and `$end` (I changed their names) variables?

Comment: @Gaurav After I apply changes suggested by you, debug shows that both variables got assigned values which is good but then I've got another error message: `Warning (2): rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Routing\Route\Route.php, line 574]` which points to `Route.php`. It's weird because I don't remember changing anything in this file.

Comment: @PHPJunior That error does not seem to be connected with your form. Some other part of your code might be causing this. You can try google ot ask [here](http://discourse.cakephp.org/).

Comment: @Gaurav I think that this may be connected to my redirect line: `return $this->redirect([$beginning, $end]);` but I've got no idea what could be the possible fix.

Comment: @Gaurav Please, add your first post as a answer and I'll accept it. Now my problem is of a different nature, so I should add a new question.

Comment: @PHPJunior **$beginning** and **$end** in your code are an array and your `export()` method is expecting a string. That might be the reason. And I hope you are still passing controller and action to `redirect()` before the parameters because your last comment is showing otherwise.